# Is there a list of all possible ways to earn and lose rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

The F.A.Q. has a list of ways you can earn or lose reputation points. However, I have found that this list is not all inclusive. For example, it is unlisted that you earn points based on a comment you put on a question or answer that is upvoted (2 points).

While not applicable to me, there are also moderator-specific points, such as reversing serial upvoting.

It would be nice if there was a list of all the keywords that can appear for a rep gain/loss, along with the respective points.

Comment: You don't get rep for a comment you put on an answer. I might be missing a bunch here, but off the top of my head: votes on your posts, acceptances, bounties, suggested edits and suspensions affect your rep.

Comment: You can find a complete list in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/200500

Comment: @Asad I thought if I commented on something that helped explain things, and someone else upvoted my comment, that I got a small amount of reputation from it. That's how it works on the Android.SE site, at least.

Comment: That can't be right. Are you sure you aren't confusing comments with edits? If you suggest an edit to a question and it gets approved, you gain +2 rep. Comments (like the ones we are conversing in right now) have zero effect on reputation.

Comment: All the ways you can earn and lose reputation *are* mentioned in the FAQ. Reversals and deletions are not mentioned because they don't directly gain/lose reputation, they *reverse* the reputation gain/loss of the previous event(s) they affect.

Comment: @ani - I agree with you to a certain extent, but due to the nature of reversal, there is confusion about sudden appearance or disappearance of reputation. Sometimes from events that are not in your control.

Comment: @Asad -  It looks like you're correct. I could have sworn I saw myself gain a couple points from an upvoted comment, but I guess it was from edits (as I try do those regularly).

Comment: @Gamecat is Toon Krijthe - You're probably right, it does look like a duplicate. I searched and was unable to find that question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already read over [this FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), but there is nothing there about gaining reputation from comments at all. You can get badges though -

- [commentator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator) - Left 10 comments
- [pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) - Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more

I agree with you that there should be a mention of reversal actions so I've [added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7238/41) another bullet point to the list.